# Converting MessageBoxImage to ImageSource WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, type-conversion

I'm try to create a custom MessageBox in WPF(c#). I need to convert MessageBoxImage to ImageSource. Is there any way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon` method ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.interop.imaging.createbitmapsourcefromhicon.aspx)) and `SystemIcons` class ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemicons.aspx)).

Example:

```
img.Source = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(
                                SystemIcons.Warning.Handle,
                                Int32Rect.Empty,
                                BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
```